# Cómo sumar Todos los salarios de un empleado

Tags: java, poo

```
package clase;


public class Empleados {

    private int id;

    private double salarioB;
    private double Retencion;



    public Empleado(int id, double salarioB, double Retencion) {
        this.id = id;
        this.salarioBase = salarioB;
        this.Retencion = Retencion;
    }

    public double Descuentos() {

        return salarioB * Retencion / 100;

    }

    public double SalarioPagar() {

        return salarioB - Descuentos();

    }
    public double totalPagos(){
      double acomulador = 0;

        for(int x=0; x<50; x++){
            acomulador=acomulador+SalarioPagar();
        }
        return acomulador;
  }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public double getSalarioB() {
        return salarioB;
    }

    public double getRetencion() {
        return Retencion;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setSalarioB(double salarioB) {
        this.salarioB = salarioB;
    }

    public void setRetencion(double Retencion) {
        this.Retencion = Retencion;
    }


}
```

Comment: Puedes publicar el resto de tu codigo?

Comment: Sin saber los valores de `salarioB` y `Descuentos()` es imposible ver el problema. Te aconsejo que uses el depurador y/o imprimas internamente los valores de las variables para saber dónde está la desviación.

Comment: Porque no puedes publicarlo? Seria mas facil ayudarte. Si hay algo personal en el codigo cambialo por algo similar que no te comprometa.

Comment: int x=0; x<50; x++ porque??? de donde sale ese 50 en el for?

Comment: Pregunto de donde sale... Que significan esos 50? 50 empleados? 50 que?

Comment: @Andrews451 . Tu salarioB no tiene ningun valor. Y en tu clase Retencion no se que hay.

Comment: te recomiendo empezar explicando tu problema y a continuacion poner el codigo, no sirve mucho ver el codigo sin contexto del problema nos obligas a ir hasta abajo para leerlo y luego subir para empezar a revisarlo

Comment: Qué código? A mi no me sale nada de código

Comment: Gracias, problema solucionado.

Comment: La descripción de la pregunta podría especificar con más detalle cuál es el problema. ¿Podrías **[edit]** la pregunta pensando en alguien que lea tu publicación y quiera entender cuál es el problema sin tener que analizar tu código? ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola necesitamos un poco mas de detalle en tu problema:

-Te sale diferente por mas o por menos, ayuda muchisimo mas si nos da un caso concreto por ejemplo: si uso el mismo sueldo para 100 empleados con sueldo base 'x' , descuentos 'n%'  deberia salirme una cantidad 'ssss'  pero me sale 'aaaa'

-Las retenciones estan como porcentaje o como cantidad (de la formula me hace pensar que estan en porcentaje, pero prefiero que lo confirmes)

necesitamos eso para poder ayudarte

el problema es que en tu for usas siempre 50 como numero de empleados, tomando los comentarios que pones en esta respuesta:

sueldo base 2000  - 10% de descuentos = 1800

pero como tu for es de 50

1800 * 50 = 90000

cambia el for para que reciba el numero de empleados y deberia salir bien, hasta donde veo el calculo del sueldo total esta bien, tu problema esta en que no usas el numero de empleados, si no una cantidad fija

Cambia tu metodo totalPagos para que reciba el total de empleados:

```
public double totalPagos( int totalEmpleados){
  double acomulador = 0;

    for(int x=0; x<totalEmpleados; x++){
        acomulador=acomulador+SalarioPagar();
    }
    return acomulador;
}
```

y cambia la llamada del metodo  mostrarDatosTotales() en la clase Interfaz para que envie el parametro n (que es donde veo que almacenas el numero de empleados)

```
System.out.println("Total  pagos: "+ Arreglo[k].totalPagos(n));
```

Comment: si tengo dos empleados  y el salario base es es 2000  y  la retencion de caada uno es del 10 % eso significa  que el total de pagos es de 3600 y la retencion total es de 400.

Comment: y cuanto te sale?

Comment: @Andrews451 el ejemplo que te da 90000, cuanto debería darte? 3600?

Comment: Gracias, problema solucionado

Answer (score 0):

Deberias cambiar tu metodo *totalPagos()*. Como te indican el for no esta bien planteado en este caso. Lo modifique de la siguiente forma

```
public double totalPagos() {
        double acomulador = SalarioPagar();

        return acomulador;
    }
```

Entonces con los datos que nos comentas obtengo por consola lo siguiente

```
Id: 1
SalarioBase: 2000.0
Porcentaje de Retencion: 10.0
Descuento: 200.0
Salario a pagar: 1800.0
--------------------------------------------------------
Id: 2
SalarioBase: 2000.0
Porcentaje de Retencion: 10.0
Descuento: 200.0
Salario a pagar: 1800.0
--------------------------------------------------------
Total  pagos: 1800.0
Total  pagos: 1800.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes una propiedad para cada tipo de salario, me imagino que tienes un metodo get para cada una de las propiedades. En el método salarioTotal lo que debes hacer es sumar cada uno de los resultados de las llamadas a esos método.
Ejemplo:

```
$contador = $this->SalarioPagar() + getSalarioB() + getSalario...()
return $contador;
```